# Full outer join in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is a Full Outer Join supported by Neo4j? I read about Optional Match but I can't quite get it to work for my scenario.

Specifically, I have a Neo4j schema with 5 entity types where certain types can connect to one another with undirected connections. The allowed connections are (Type1, Type2), (Type2, Type3), (Type3, Type4) and (Type4, Type5). The connections are not directional. I want to perform the equivalent of full outer join between these types. e.g. if the only connections are `e11:Type1--e21:Type2`, `e22:Type2--e31:Type3`, `e32:Type3--e41:Type4` and `e42:Type4:e51:Type5` then the full outer join should result in:

| Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 | Type5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e11 | e21 | null | null | null |
| null | e22 | e31 | null | null |
| null | null | e32 | e41 | null |
| null | null | null | e42 | e51 |

Comment: Is this schema such that this will always be the desired sequence? If so, you might consider adding placeholder nodes for each type to represent a null, but can continue linking to the next node of the given type. That way a MATCH can start at a null placeholder node and continue the chain.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of a better query than looking for each type pair, checking that they are not connected to other types, and then combining each sub-query with `UNION`. This results in a quite big query. Maybe someone else can think of a more dynamic query.

```
MATCH (n1:Type1)--(n2:Type2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)--(n3:Type3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3)--(n4:Type4)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n4)--(n5:Type5)
WITH n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
WHERE n3 IS NULL
RETURN n1, n2, n3, n4, n5

UNION

MATCH (n2:Type2)--(n3:Type3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)--(n1:Type1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3)--(n4:Type4)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n4)--(n5:Type5)
WITH n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
WHERE n1 IS NULL AND n4 IS NULL
RETURN n1, n2, n3, n4, n5

UNION

MATCH (n3:Type3)--(n4:Type4)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3)--(n2:Type2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)--(n1:Type1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n4)--(n5:Type5)
WITH n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
WHERE n2 IS NULL AND n5 IS NULL
RETURN n1, n2, n3, n4, n5

UNION

MATCH (n4:Type4)--(n5:Type5)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n4)--(n3:Type3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3)--(n2:Type2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)--(n1:Type1)
WITH n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
WHERE n3 IS NULL
RETURN n1, n2, n3, n4, n5
```

**UPDATE:**

Without the requirement of returning `NULL` the query can be shortened:

```
MATCH (n1:Type1)--(n2:Type2)
WHERE NOT (n2)--(:Type3)
RETURN n1, n2

UNION

MATCH (n1:Type2)--(n2:Type3)
WHERE NOT (n1)--(:Type1) AND NOT (n2)--(:Type4)
RETURN n1, n2

UNION

MATCH (n1:Type3)--(n2:Type4)
WHERE NOT (n1)--(:Type2) AND NOT (n2)--(:Type5)
RETURN n1, n2

UNION

MATCH (n1:Type4)--(n2:Type5)
WHERE NOT (n1)--(:Type3)
RETURN n1, n2
```

Comment: This was helpful, but note that I don't need to enforce that all the elements are null except for two (it was just an example). I think if you just remove the WITH and WHERE clauses from each of the union elements I'll be able to accept the answer (assuming nothing more concise comes up in a day or two).

Comment: That makes it a bit easier. See my updated answer. However, I still couldn't figure out a more dynamic, shorter query without `UNION`.